# Problem when installing intel i40e driver

Tags: networking, wireless, drivers, permissions, virtualbox

i am running ubuntu 14.04 on virtualmachine. wifi wasn't working, instead it appears as a 'wired connection 1' and can't choose a different wifi network.

I looked to see if i needed a driver because it couldnt be anything else, wifi works fine outside of virtual machine, I downloaded the intel i40e driver as its the only thing i think could help (ive tried countless of other solved questions non worked).

When installing it I put in the command `make install` under the `/home/eye-parce/i40e-1.2.48/src/` directory. when I do so I get '`error... permission denied`'. I tried with super user and nothing happened

"`eye-parce@eyeparce-VirtualBox:~/i40e-1.2.48/src$ sudo make install`

[sudo] password for eye-parce:

`eye-parce@eyeparce-VirtualBox:~/i40e-1.2.48/src$`"

Answer (score 0):

On your host is where you must connect to the WiFi and you will see that the virtual machine connects directly to your wifi but appears as wired connection. Select the wifi you want to use on your host machine not the virtual machine :)

Comment: Yeah I had tried that with success but is that the only way around it? I wanted to be able to stay on virtual machine and switch networks when needed.